# Udev rule for input device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, driver, udev

I have a camera device that has an input device listed under `/dev/input`. I would like to add that input device to the group `plugdev`.

When I plug in the camera:

```
[  704.406837] input: See3CAM_CU51 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/input/input21
[  705.157657] hid-generic 0003:2560:C152.0007: hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [e-con Systems See3CAM_CU51] on usb-0000:00:1
```

It's now symlinked under `/dev/input/by-id`

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 31 10:50 usb-e-con_Systems_See3CAM_CU51_172A0202-event-if00 -> ../event20
```

However, event20 has the following permissions:

```
0 crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 84 Aug 31 10:50 event20
```

I've written udev rules for the hiddevice itself with success, but for some reason, I can't get the rule right for the input device.  Here's what I've tried:

```
KERNEL=="input", ATTR{name}=="See3CAM_CU51", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev"
```

But it does not appear to work.  There's not a huge deal of examples of changing the ownership of input devices out there (that I've found at least).

**Update:**

When I change my udev rule to

```
    KERNEL=="input", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev"
```

that is, I leave out the device name, all my input devices in /dev/input have the correct permissions.

So basically, I'm saying "every input device gets set to mode 0666, and belong to the plugdev group", which *works*.  But adding the ATTR{name}== breaks it.

Here's the output of udevadm info:

```
udevadm info -a -p /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/input/input21

looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/input/input21':
KERNEL=="input21"
SUBSYSTEM=="input"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{name}=="See3CAM_CU51"
ATTR{phys}=="usb-0000:00:14.0-2/button"
ATTR{properties}=="0"
ATTR{uniq}==""
```

It should be working, I have the correct name set for the device, what stupid mistake am I making?

Comment: Try to use the Kernel name of "input21". Example: `KERNEL=="input21", ATTR{name}=="See3CAM_CU51", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev"`

Comment: But if I plug the camera in at a later time, it's not guaranteed to be input21.  Maybe I can do the same with the symlink instead.

Answer (score 1):

udev rules support string matching, you're probably looking for:

```
ACTION=="...", KERNEL=="input[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ...
```

to match on the specific action for *any* `inputN` devices, then you can add your `ATTR` filter(s) to select the specific device.